# Apache in Ubuntu: How Access by IP to multipe sites in the same webserver?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, url, ip, webserver

I have a Webserver with **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Apache 2.4**. In that, I have in **/var/inetpub/** some sites' files. Example:

```
/var/inetpub/site1.com/... 
/var/inetpub/site2.com/...
/var/inetpub/site3.com/... 
/var/inetpub/site4.com/...
```

I can access this sites when I am in my LAN, editng my computer's **hosts** file, adding the server IP, like:

```
192.168.1.10 site1.com
192.168.1.10 site2.com
192.168.1.10 site3.com
192.168.1.10 site4.com
```

With this, I can open my browser and paste the site1.com or site2.com and the web is displayed. But, now I need this sames sites to be visible in my mobile. So, before getting into something like trying to modify the equivalent in the mobile phone to the **hosts** file (which worth mentioning that I tried a long time ago, I lost a whole day and it did not work), I wonder if there was a simpler alternative, such as being able to access the sites through IP.

Right now, if the type the ip (**192.168.1.10**) in my mobile phone browser, obviously connected in my LAN, it shows me the first site (site1.com). So, 
Is there any configuration that allow me to do the same with the other site? I don´t know, something like:

```
http://192.168.1.10/site1.com
http://192.168.1.10/site2.com
http://192.168.1.10/site3.com
http://192.168.1.10/site4.com
```

Maybe?

Someone could tell me that it would be easier add the urls  to the local DNS of my network, but at the moment it is not an option, since I do not have access to such configuration, and getting it or having someone with such access to help me, is something... Complicated and slow.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I thank it’s more easy if you can edit your mobile's hosts.But it not easy,you need got the root access of your android mobile.And i don't know how to do this on ios.

Optionally,edit the router's dns is work too,but it not easy too...

There is a option,you are build a DNS server on your ubuntu,then change you mobile's DNS. But it's difficult.